# Unable to use "Base64ImageUploadAdapter" with ckeditor build ("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic") - Vue JS version 2

Tags: vuejs2, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to upload image and insert in the ckeditor box but unable to do so.

```
/*Import code*/

<script>

    import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

    import { Base64UploadAdapter } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload';

    /*Initialization and configuration*/

    data() {

        return {

            editor: ClassicEditor,

            editorConfig: {

                toolbar: {

                    plugins:[Base64ImageUploadAdapter],

                    items: [

                        'heading',

                        'numberedList',

                        'bulletedList',

                        'bold',

                        'italic',

                        'link',

                        'undo',

                        'redo',

                        'imageUpload'

                    ],

                },

            },

        };

    }

</script>
```

Using this way gives the following error:

**"ckeditor-duplicated-modules"**

If I'm removing "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload" then it gives me a different error as following:

**"Base64UploadAdapter" not defined.**

I tried another way in which I was getting the following error

**"filerepository-no-upload-adapter: Upload adapter is not defined"**